# Show few items from an Array using onchange Event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an event Listener to display only 5 items in array if user selects eg: option 5 in the html form select.

```js
const Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="1">5</option>
            <option value="2">10</option>
          </select>
```

EDIT: I am showing the array in a list. I am getting a user input and showing the Li like below.

```js
Array.forEach((item) => {
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className =
        'list-group-item';
      button.innerText += item;
      List.appendChild(button);
 });
```

Comment: Where are you showing the array?

Comment: a <Li> element.

Comment: Could you provide that HTML as well?

Comment: "if user selects option 5 and 10 is user selects option 10." This yo need to clarify a bit more

Comment: "is user selects option 10." ?

Comment: i intend adding an event listener to my html such that when a user selects eg: option 5 in the form select he is shown on 5 items on the list.

Comment: Ah ok so if. a 10 is selectd 10 items are displayd..?

Comment: yes that's what i am trying to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

const selectBox = document.querySelector(".form-select");
const List = document.getElementById("itemList");

function applySelection() {
  let selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
  let output = []
  for (i = 0; i < selectedOption; ++i) {
    output.push(Array[i])
  }
  List.innerHTML = ''
  output.forEach((item) => {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.className = 'list-group-item';
    button.innerText += item;
    List.appendChild(button);
  });
}

selectBox.addEventListener("change", applySelection);
applySelection()
```

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value="1">5</option>
  <option value="2">10</option>
</select>

<div id="itemList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onChange like this easily! hope this will help you now.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsFunction(value)
{
    const list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry']
    const items = list.slice(0, value)
    alert(items);
    
    const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    
    const items2 = numbers.slice(0, value)
    alert(items2);
}
</script>

<select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am looking for a proper way to add the event listener to the form select so as to achieve this.

Comment: Please can you explain your query in proper way?

Comment: Okay thanks. I am displaying a list like a todo list to user from an input. I have a form select with 2 options 5 and 10. I want to show user only 5 items in list if user selects 5 from the dropdown.  i do not know how to implement the onchange event properly to achieve this.

Comment: OK, now its clear. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select class="form-select" onChange=onChange={(e) =>
                  applyFilters(e.target.value)
                } aria-label="Default select example">
                <option value="1">5</option>
                <option value="2">10</option>
</select>
```

In React component->

```
 applyFilters(let length){
    const filteredArray = wholeArray.slice(0, length) 
    setState(filteredArray)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So here you have an example of what you can do..

```js
var arr =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


var event = document.getElementsByClassName('form-select')

var count = 5; 
 

event[0].addEventListener('change',function(e){
  count = e.target.value
  displayList()
})


function displayList(){
  
var itemList =   document.getElementById('itemList')
itemList.innerHTML ="";
  for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    itemList.innerHTML += arr[i]
    
  }
}
displayList()
```

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
          </select>
  
  
  <div id="itemList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```js
const arr=["apple","orange","banana","kiwi","strawberry","cherry","pineapple","melon","pear","mango"];
const list= document.querySelector("div"),
      sel=document.querySelector("select");
sel.addEventListener("change",ev=>
list.innerHTML=arr.slice(0,ev.target.value).map(li=> 
  '<button class="list-group-item">'+li+'</button>').join("")
);
sel.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option value="5">5 items</option>
        <option value="10">10 items</option>
      </select>
<div></div>
```